# Apache Redirect Help 'Pretty Links'

Tags: apache-2.4, https

I have https://waders.tech I want to be able to go to https://waders.tech/pics.html but only have to type https://waders.tech/pics
would this work:?

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://waders.tech/$1 [L]
```

What ever Cpanel uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static files, enabling `Options +MultiViews` is sufficient. No rewrites needed.